# Disable taking images in any orientation other than Portrait AVFoundation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, avfoundation, uideviceorientation

I am using `AVFoundation` to show the camera.

I would like to prevent the camera itself to rotate so the viewer will see the camera only in portrait and the images will be taken only in portrait mode.

I defined `Supported Interface Orientation` to support portrait only and the view itself is being displayed only in portrait mode, but not the camera - is being rotated with the device orientation

How can I force the `AVFoundation` camera to be displayed and capture images only in portrait like the UIViewController?

My code to set the camera:

```
AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer* lay = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:self.sess];
UIView *view = [self videoPreviewView];
CALayer *viewLayer = [view layer];
[viewLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
CGRect bounds = [view bounds];
[lay setFrame:bounds];
if ([lay respondsToSelector:@selector(connection)])
 {
   if ([lay.connection isVideoOrientationSupported])
   {
      [lay.connection setVideoOrientation:AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait];
    }
 }
 [lay setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
 [viewLayer insertSublayer:lay below:[[viewLayer sublayers] objectAtIndex:0]];
 self.previewLayer = lay;
```

Comment: Not sure about your Q. Nothing will force the user not to rotate his iPhone. So you want to allow recording video only when your interface is in portrait? Or better: the device is only in vertical position?

Comment: No - I would like the camera not to rotate to portrait - the same way that I can force the UiViewcontroller to stay in portrait position

Comment: I don't understand the problem. In iOS6, if I set supported interface orientations to portrait only (in target summary), my camera preview stays put along with the rest of the interface, whatever the device orientation. Does yours not do this? Obviously the camera preview _image_ rotates with the device so that the horizon remains level - is that what you want to disable, so the horizon remains fixed as per the portrait view, whatever the orientation?

Comment: Yes. This is exactly what I want to do

Comment: @HeWas Was And also that the taken picture will only be in portrait

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a partial answer based on my understanding of your question (which differs from the other answers you have had).

You have the app locked to portrait orientation. So the status bar is always at the portrait top of the phone regardless of the phone's orientation. This successfully locks your interface, including your AVCapture interface. But you want to also lock the raw image feed from the camera so that the image horizon is always parallel with the status bar.

This will ideally need to be done *continuously* - so that if you have the camera at a 45degree angle the image will be counter-rotated 45 degrees. Otherwise, most of the time, the image will not be aligned correctly (the alternative is that it is always out of line until your 90degree orientation switch updates, which would swivel the image 90 degrees).

To do this you need to use Core Motion and the accelerometer. You want to get angle of the phone's Y-axis to true vertical and rotate the image accordingly. See here for geometry details:

[iPhone orientation -- how do I figure out which way is up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12994219/iphone-orientation-how-do-i-figure-out-which-way-is-up?rq=1)

Using Core Motion, trigger this method from viewDidLoad

```
- (void)startAccelerometerUpdates {
    self.coreMotionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
    if ([self.coreMotionManager isAccelerometerAvailable] == YES) {
        CGFloat updateInterval = 0.1;
            // Assign the update interval to the motion manager
        [self.coreMotionManager setAccelerometerUpdateInterval:updateInterval];
        [self.coreMotionManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] 
           withHandler: ^(CMAccelerometerData *accelerometerData, NSError *error) {
             CGFloat angle =  -atan2( accelerometerData.acceleration.x, 
                                      accelerometerData.acceleration.y) 
                               + M_PI ;
             CATransform3D rotate = CATransform3DMakeRotation(angle, 0, 0, 1);
             self.previewLayer.transform = rotate;

         }];
    }
}
```

> <sup>a</sup> [image: upright] <sup>b</sup>  [image: 45deg] <sup>c</sup>  [image: 90deg]
>
> <sup>phone held (a) portrait;  (b) rotated ~30deg;  (c) landscape</sup>
>    .

You may find this is a little jumpy, and there is a bit of a lag between the device movement and the view. You can play with the updateInterval, and get in deeper with other Core Motion trickery to dampen the movement. (<s>I have not treated the case of the phone being exactly upside down, and if you hold the camera face down or face up, the result is undefined</s> *fixed with updated code/ use of `atan2`*).

Now orientation is reasonably correct, but your image does not fit your view. There is not a lot you can do about this as the format of the raw camera feed is fixed by the physical dimensions of it's sensor array. The workaround is to zoom the image so that you have enough excess image data at all angles to enable you to crop the image to fit the portrait format you want.

*Either* in Interface Builder:

- set your previewLayer's view to square centered on it's superview, with width and height equal to the diagonal of the visible image area (sqrt (width<sup>2</sup>+height<sup>2</sup>)

*Or* in code:

```
- (void)resizeCameraView
{
    CGSize size = self. videoPreviewView.bounds.size;
    CGFloat diagonal = sqrt(pow(size.width,2)+pow(size.height,2));
    diagonal = 2*ceil(diagonal/2);  //rounding
    self.videoPreviewView.bounds = (CGRect){0,0,diagonal,diagonal};
}
```

If you do this in code, `resizeCameraView` should work if you call it from your `viewDidLoad`. Make sure that `self.videoPreviewView` is your IBOutlet reference to the correct view.

Now when you take a photo, you will capture the whole of the 'raw' image data from the camera's array, which will be in landscape format. It will be saved with an orientation flag for display rotation. But what you may want is to save the photo as seen onscreen. This means that you will have to rotate and crop the photo to match your onscreen view before saving it, and remove it's orientation metadata. That's for you to work out (the other part of the 'partial answer'): I suspect you might decide that this whole approach doesn't get you what you want (I think what you'd really like is a camera sensor that hardware-rotates against the rotation of the device to keep the horizon stable).

*update*
changed `startAccelerometerUpdates` to get angle from `atan2` instead of `acos`, smoother and takes account of all directions without fiddling

*update 2*
From your comments, it seems your rotated preview layer is getting stuck? I cannot replicate your error, it must be some other place in your code or settings.

So that you can check with clean code, I have added my solution into [Apple's AVCam project](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html), so you can check it against that. Here is what to do:

- add the Core Motion framework to AVCam.

In AVCamViewController.m

- `#import <CoreMotion/CoreMotion.h>`
- add  my `startAccelerometerUpdates` method
- add my `resizeCameraView` method (stick both of these methods near the top of the class file or you may get confused, there are more than one `@implementation`s in that file)
- add the line: `[self resizeCameraView];` to `viewDidLoad` (it can be the first line of the method)
- add the property
  `@property (strong, nonatomic) CMMotionManager* coreMotionManager`
  to the @interface (it doesn't need to be a property, but my method assumes it exists, so if you don't add it you will have to modify my method instead).

In `startAccelerometerUpdates` change this line:

```
    self.previewLayer.transform = rotate;
```

to:

```
    self.captureVideoPreviewLayer.transform = rotate;
```

also, in the Objects list in `AVCamViewController.xib`, move the videoPreview View above the ToolBar (otherwise when you enlarge it you cover the controls)

Be sure to disable rotations - for iOS<6.0, that is already true, but for 6.0+ you need to select just portrait in supported orientations in the target summary.

I think that is a *complete* list of changes I made to AVCam, and the rotation/orientation is all working very well. I suggest you try doing the same. If you can get this to work smoothly, you know there is some other glitch in your code somewhere. If you still find your rotations stick, I would be curious to know more about your hardware and software environment such as which devices are you testing on.

I am compiling on XCode 4.6/OSX10.8.2, and testing on:

```
- iPhone4S  /  iOS5.1  
- iPhone3G  /  iOS6.1  
- iPad mini /  iOS6.1
```

All results are smooth and accurate.

Comment: I tried your solution again. I updated my answer with how my screen looks like after trying it, and when holding the iphone rotated to right but straight. I didn't try it on AVCAM, but I don't have much on my code to prevent it

Comment: @Odelya, it looks like you just didn't enlarge the camera view (the `resizeCameraView` method isn't getting called correctly).

Comment: If the phone is not rotated to right when I hold it, it does fill the square. Is it something that I have to call via notifications (it happens only if I rotate to right)

Comment: @Odelya, in `resizeCameraView` did you change the property name in my code -  self.cameraPreview - to the one your code uses - self.videoPreviewView?

Comment: You mean to replace my code from the question that sets the image with the resizeCameraView method?

Comment: @Odelya - no, don't replace your code, which is fine. Call `resizeCameraView` just before your code, that should work (or, as I say, you could call it as the first thing in `ViewDidLoad`). It is just enlarging the view so that you don't get the edges cropped as you rotate.

Comment: @Odelya - and make sure that your videoPreviewView is BEHIND your camera controls in your IB layout - otherwise it will cover them up when you enlarge it.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you need to use this method to restrict the camera rotation.

```
AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = [CameraVC connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo fromConnections:[imageCaptureOutput connections]];
if ([videoConnection isVideoOrientationSupported])
{
    [videoConnection setVideoOrientation:[UIDevice currentDevice].orientation];
}
```

Assuming your preview layer is defined as property, can use

```
[self.previewLayer setOrientation:[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]];
```

In your case you can replace [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] by UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait

edited

Try to add the preview layer when you actually need it.
Example

```
preview = [[self videoPreviewWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)] retain];
[self.view addSubview:preview];
```

The videoPreviewWithFrame function.

```
- (UIView *) videoPreviewWithFrame:(CGRect) frame 
{
  AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *tempPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc]initWithSession:[self captureSession]];
  [tempPreviewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
  tempPreviewLayer.frame = frame;

  UIView* tempView = [[UIView alloc] init];
  [tempView.layer addSublayer:tempPreviewLayer];
  tempView.frame = frame;

  [tempPreviewLayer autorelease];
  [tempView autorelease];
  return tempView;
}
```

Comment: I edited my question. 1. I already set the orientation to Portrait in the video connection. Regarding the preview layer - setOrientation is deprecated, so I need to write: self.previewLayer.connection which is the same as I am already doing no?

Comment: I have edited my answer. Try to implement which I have written after the edited line.

Comment: if ([captureVideoPreviewLayer respondsToSelector:@selector(connection)])
{
    if ([captureVideoPreviewLayer.connection isVideoOrientationSupported])
    {
        [captureVideoPreviewLayer.connection setVideoOrientation:self.interfaceOrientation];
    }
}
else
{
    // Deprecated in 6.0; here for backward compatibility
    if ([captureVideoPreviewLayer isOrientationSupported])
    {
        [captureVideoPreviewLayer setOrientation:self.interfaceOrientation];
    }                
}

Comment: Your setting videoOrientation which is only in iOS6 so for backward compatibility use the setOrientation in the else part.

Comment: Not able to understand as to what is not working. It would be easy to  understand if you upload few screenshots. Did you try with imagePicker? By default imagePicker stays in portrait so I guess it can help you.

Comment: See He Was comment on my question - I wan't to disable the camera to rotate when the user rotates the device

Comment: PreviewLayer.orientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait works like gem but is deprecated in iOS6. Don't know the work around. You can use this and try. I tried and its working.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your previewlayer is added to a viewcontroller view. Do this in `viewDidLoad` :

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

and define the selector as:

```
- (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification*)notification {
    UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
    if ([self.previewlayer respondsToSelector:@selector(orientation)]) {
        //for iOS5
        if (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
            self.previewlayer.orientation = (AVCaptureVideoOrientation)UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
        }
    } else {
        //for iOS6
        if (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
            self.previewlayer.connection.videoOrientation = (AVCaptureVideoOrientation)UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** put `tempPreviewLayer` in the property `self.previewlayer` .

This will force the preview layer to portrait position when the device orientation changes.

**EDIT**

you can also add this in ur 'shouldAutoRotate` method of the viewController

```
    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
    {
        // Return YES for supported orientations
        if ([self.previewlayer respondsToSelector:@selector(orientation)]) {
            if (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
                self.previewlayer.orientation = (AVCaptureVideoOrientation)UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
            }
        } else {
            if (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
                self.previewlayer.connection.videoOrientation = (AVCaptureVideoOrientation)UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
            }
        }

        return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
    }
```

for ios6 over ride these two and check.

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    //UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
    //return (
    //interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft |
    //interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;//(UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}
```

before `return` in these two methods apend the code ..and in the notification that i gave, see if its called when you roate the device.

Comment: did you try it? add `[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];` before adding the notification. This works perfectly for me, it locks the preview layer in the orientation i want.

Comment: what is the note to put tempPreviewLayer in the property? what do you mean by that?

Comment: take a property `@property (nonatomic, retain) AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewlayer;` and do `self.previewlayer =  tempPreviewLayer` in your `videoPreviewWithFrame` method after the line `tempPreviewLayer.frame = frame;` and then onwards use `self.previewlayer` evrywhere

Comment: And yes - I tried the code the method is being called, but the previewLayer is not locked in portrait.I am using iOS6

Comment: self.previewlayer = tempPreviewLayer? what is the tempPreviewLayer?

Comment: tempPreviewLayer  is the one in ur example code. if its in iOS6 then over ride the  two new rotation api's and check

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24374/discussion-between-croyneaus4u-and-odelya)

Comment: AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = [CameraVC connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo fromConnections:[imageCaptureOutput connections]];
if ([videoConnection isVideoOrientationSupported])
{
    [videoConnection setVideoOrientation:[UIDevice currentDevice].orientation];
} was not getting recognized until u give it after specifying output setting. Try to set output settings and then add code.